# Using the iPhones Multi-Touch Keyboard Search Button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, multitouch-keyboard

I have a regular text field on a view and I'd like to make use of the search button on the iPhones keyboard. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this. There doesn't seem to be any event exposed that I can wire up that specifically relates to the search button on the keyboard. I've googled around, but I also haven't found anything related to this subject.

Comment: Are you asking how to display "Search" on the keyboard or how to make the Search button trigger an action? (or both)

Comment: I managed to find how display the search button, I just couldn't figure how to make it work. Thank you again for your response. That was exactly what I wasn't able to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the keyboard display the blue "Search" button by setting the return key type.

```
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
```

Set the delegate of your text field to your controller and implement the 'textFieldShouldReturn:' method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    /* Do some searching here */
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly.